# Get vimeo video info (Python) --- Different responses

Tags: python, django, vimeo, pyvimeo

When I make authorized call to [Developer API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D) to get video info for a specific video then I get response:

```
{
...
"files": [
    ...
    ...
    {
        "quality": "hd",
        "type": "video/mp4",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 720,
        "link": "LINK",
        "created_time": "Time",
        "fps": value,
        "size": size,
        "md5": "value",
        "link_secure": "link_source"
    },
    ...
    ...
],

"download": [
    ...
    ...
    {
        "quality": "source",
        "type": "source",
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 1080,
        "expires": "time",
        "link": "link",
        "created_time": "time",
        "fps": value,
        "size": size,
        "md5": "value"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
}
```

I am using `Pyvimeo==0.3.2` and `Pyvimeo==1.0.0` for Vimeo.

But when I hit "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{vimeo_id}" (with Client_id and Authorization) from my server or from POSTMAN then I get only:

```
{
...
"download": [
...
{
    "quality": "source",
    "type": "source",
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "expires": "time",
    "link": "link",
    "created_time": "time",
    "fps": value,
    "size": size,
    "md5": "value"
},
...
]
...
}
```

There is not key "files" in API response. Why I am not getting "files" key in video response ?

There is no any such update in API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Make the request with this header:

```
{ "Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.1" }
```

(Use version 3.1 instead of the default, 3.4)